# How to define common route body in camel configuration?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I have two `route` in camel configuration

route1

```
    <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:soapProxy1?dataFormat=PAYLOAD" />
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
          <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Contents-type">
          <constant>application/octet-stream</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="SOAPAction">
          <constant>vc</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Accept">
          <constant>application/xml</constant>
        </setHeader>

        <to uri="bean:samlWsBean" />            

        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${in.header.isvalid} contains "true"</simple>
                <to uri="cxf:bean:backendService?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>     
                <to uri="velocity:file:///path/samlerrorresponse.vm"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
```

route2

```
    <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:soapProxy2?dataFormat=PAYLOAD" />
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
          <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Contents-type">
          <constant>application/octet-stream</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="SOAPAction">
          <constant>vc</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Accept">
          <constant>application/xml</constant>
        </setHeader>

        <to uri="bean:samlWsBean" />            

        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${in.header.isvalid} contains "true"</simple>
                <to uri="cxf:bean:backendService?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>     
                <to uri="velocity:file:///path/samlerrorresponse.vm"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
```

there is only one line difference in both two routes.

one have this

```
<from uri="cxf:bean:soapProxy1?dataFormat=PAYLOAD" />
```

another have this

```
<from uri="cxf:bean:soapProxy2?dataFormat=PAYLOAD" />
```

so can i put common body in some where else in configuration and refer in both routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When no one respond on my question i was start searching again online and I have found solution like this

```
<camel:route id="myCommonPartOfFlow">
  <camel:from uri="direct-vm:common-in"/>
  [common part]
</camel:route>
```

and then you can invoke like this

```
<camel:to uri="direct-vm:common-in/>
```

for more help see [this](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) and [this](http://camel.apache.org/direct-vm.html), hope this will may help someone else.

Comment: Some of us do sleep. Yes you can use the VM or SEDA component for this. SEDA is great if both the routes are in the same CamelContext like in your case. VM is great if the routes are on the same JVM. You could also use JMS for this but it adds overhead. Just keep in mind that the SEDA and VM components are not persisted i.e. message can go lost during a crash. JMS has persistence and is thus more suited for a reliable queue.

Comment: thanks to explaining more about VM and SEDA. in my case there is no need of persisting message during crash. only log trace will be sufficient which we are logging.